# Updating the master-page does not reflect all the pages in Wiki site

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, javascript, custom-masterpage

I needed to add expand and collapse Quick launch since there are no out of the box feature. I had to add a CSS and js file to the masterpage. I copied existing seattle  master page, renamed it and added the below .js and cs file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/General/Community%20Portal/IT/test/SiteAssets/Accodion/SP2013Accordion.css">
<script src="https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/General/Community%20Portal/IT/test/SiteAssets/Accodion/SP2013Accordion.js"></script>
```

It works when you see the site setting and site content page not any of the new wiki pages i have created.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

To safeguard yourself against Microsoft overwriting your customization it is recommended to use Custom Actions instead. Avoid at all times, directly modifying the masterpage.

That being said, some thing to check for

1. You have checked in your masterpage, but you might have to publish it too. Go to the masterpage gallery and publish the masterpage.
2. Open your console logs and check for 404 errors, your masterpage might be working but you probably aren't seeing any changes because of incorrect paths.

**Update**

Check your settings here `<your_site>_layouts/15/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx` both the site master page and system master page must be set as the one you modified.

Comment: by publishing do you mean make the changes and save?. I went to masterpage in sharepoint designer and made a copy of the existing site master page and included the css and js file. surprisingly all the pages other than wiki got updated. For example if you go to site contents or site settings you can see the changes added to the master page is reflected, but when you create a new wiki page the css or js file added to the master page are not getting reflected

Comment: To safeguard yourself against Microsoft overwriting your customization it is recommended to use Custom Actions instead. Avoid at all times, directly modifying the masterpage.  I am not aware of this process can you advise some steps ?

Comment: Did you check if you've set the master page correctly. There are 2 places one for system UI and one for other pages. Your comment that it works for system settings and site contents makes me think this hasn't been done.

Comment: Check this out regarding user custom actions. https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Guidance/blob/master/articles/custom-actions-sharepoint-add-in.md

Comment: I can only see 4 master pages seattle, oslo, minimal and v4. Seattle was the default one so i have changed it. and it worked only for the site contents and site settings.

Comment: Updated the answer. Please have a look.